# ASP.NET Core MVC .cshtml (Razor) file changes not reflected?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application (controllers + views).

I wrote some code changes in `.cs` & `.cshtml` files.

But after deploying the code changes to the hosting environment, only `.cs` file changes are reflected (like I have added few trace log in `Startup.cs` file)

The `.cshtml` (Razor) file changes are not reflected in the hosting environment.

I tried a few things like

- enabled "AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()"
- add few log in .cshtml file

Can you please help me out here?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Make sure cache is cleared to rule that out at the very least as this often can affect changes in front end files.

Comment: Are you sure you deployed the PrecompiledViews dll as well as the main application dll?

Comment: PrecompiledViews means "projectaname.Views.dll" ? yes this is showing in publish folders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have your views refresh in .NET Core 3+, you need to install [the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation/) from NuGet, and then enable it from your `Startup.cs` file.

[image]

As seen in the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
```

Or:

```
{
    services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
```